# React useCallback instead of useEffect for animation

Tags: reactjs, usecallback

Following along from a Scrimba tutorial on React Hooks, I've been trying to use, `useEffect` and `useCallback` for ways of preventing a component from re-rendering during requestAnimationFrame. I currently have the `Playground`component that updates and renders `count` state and a child `<Calculate />` component that counts the number of renders.

Below, I'm using useCallback and It seems to be working. Does anyone know if the return function works in a useCallback hook to clean up the requestAnimationframe as it would in the useEffect hook? I've used it in the below code, but not sure how to check if 'cancelAnimationFrame' is being implemented?

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react'


export default function Playground() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const cb = useCallback(()=>{
      let anim,
        loop = () => {
           setCount(prev => prev + 1) 
           anim = requestAnimationFrame(loop)
        }
        loop()
        return()=> cancelAnimationFrame(anim)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
    <h1>{count}</h1>
      <Calculate cb={cb} />
    </>
  )
}

const Calculate = React.memo(({ cb }) =>{
  cb()
  const renderCount = useRef(1)
  return <div>{renderCount.current++}</div>
})
```

Comment: your usage of `useCallback` seems wrong, it seems you need `useEffect` instead. `useCallback` memoizes function passed to it and only recreates new function is any of the dependency passed to it in `[]` changes

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know it seems wrong but it works...